# Crystal Report: Centering reports within report viewer control

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

Looking for a way to center a report within the .NET Crystal Reports viewer control when the containing form is maximized.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it centers the report by default? I put the crv onto a form and set the dock to fill. In fact, I don't know how to get it to not center the report.

Answer (score 0):

On the DOCK property of the viewer control, set it to FILL.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ReportViewer control DOCK property to FILL and set the Maximized property of the form programmatically after calling the Show method. If it is set in the design time it's not working. See below my sample code.

```
Me.rptViewer.Zoom(100) 

Me.rptViewer.Show()

Me.Show()

Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```